# Exteding a class from lazy loaded script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a ts class that extends another class, but the parent class is inside of a js lib that is loaded lazily so it is not recognized by ts after transpiling (everything is angular cli default):

> TSClassFile

```
export class TSClass extends JSClassFromScriptFile {
    constructor() {
         super();
     }
}
```

> AngularComponent Using TsClass

```
@Component({...})
export class AngularComponent {
  testTsClass: TsClass;
  constructor() {
     // loads scriptFile and initiates test param
     this.loadScript('scriptFile').then( res => {
        this.testTsClass = new TsClass();
     });
  }

  // Adds script tag to head el with src of scriptName
  loadScript(scriptName): Promise {
      ...
  }
}
```

I found a "solution" which I'm not happy with because it has no reusability whatsoever  :

```
...
testTsClass: any;
constructor() {
   this.loadScript('scriptFile').then( res => {
        class TSClass extends JSClassFromScriptFile {
             constructor() {
                 super();
             }
        }
        this.testTsClass = new TsClass();
   });
}
...
```

so any more elegant way is much appreciated.